# Where can I read about the behavior of the postgress casting operators?

Tags: postgresql, cast

I want to do something like this:

```
alter table foos
alter column bar type bool using bar::boolean;
```

`bar` is currently a text column. Some experimentation shows that postgres will do things like convert a string `"t"` to boolean `true`. In my case this is great, but I'd like to read the full behavior before using this. I can't seem to find where this documentation is.

Comment: Have you checked: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/ ?

Comment: Looks very interesting, but I believe does not answer my question about the behavior of `::boolean`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Thought your question was about cast in general. If I Where to guess, any nonempty string will be treated as true

Comment: postgresql does not treat a string as true or false,  postgresql does very little autocasting like Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior for [boolean](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html)

typically you have to go look up every type and to see how it can be cast or look for a function to do the casting

here is a [link](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)

Postgresql also supports [Create Cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html)

Information on the [pg_cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/catalog-pg-cast.html)

Comment: thanks! the postgresql.org docs are surprising in that they don't say that postgres accepts `'t'` and `'f'` but I know that it does.

Comment: @JohnBachir they do basically say that, though, in that section that was linked.

Comment: where do they say that?

Comment: Unique prefixes of these strings are also accepted, for example t or n. Leading or trailing whitespace is ignored, and case does not matter.

Comment: ahhh, i wasn't parsing that correctly at first. okay so `'t'` works and `'tru'` would as well. ::tests it:: it works! kool

Answer (score 2):

This is in the PostgreSQL manual [section on the boolean data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-boolean.html):

> Boolean constants can be represented in SQL queries by the SQL key words `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NULL`.
>
> The datatype input function for type `boolean` accepts these string representations for the “true” state:
>
> ```
> true
> yes
> on
> 1
> ```
>
> and these representations for the “false” state:
>
> ```
> false
> no
> off
> 0
> ```
>
> Unique prefixes of these strings are also accepted, for example `t` or `n`. Leading or trailing whitespace is ignored, and case does not matter.
>
> The datatype output function for type `boolean` always emits either `t` or `f` […]

Comment: Thanks! see my comment here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256062/where-can-i-read-about-the-behavior-of-the-postgress-casting-operators?noredirect=1#comment505012_256064